# Flutter build fails: copyWith' isn't defined for the class 'RouteSettings'

Tags: flutter, dart

Am getting an error, which seems to be from an internal package dependency *navigator.dart*

> Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you
> notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
> "--enable-software-rendering". Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK
> built for x86 in debug mode...
> /C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/states_rebuilder-4.4.0/lib/src/navigate/rm_navigator.dart:167:44:
> Error: **The method 'copyWith' isn't defined for the class
> 'RouteSettings'**.
>
> - 'RouteSettings' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart'
>   ('/D:/FlutterSDK/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
>   a method named 'copyWith'.
>   final p = resolvePage(settings.copyWith(name: n));
>   ^^^^^^^^ /C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/states_rebuilder-4.4.0/lib/src/navigate/rm_navigator.dart:227:27:
>   Error: **The method 'copyWith' isn't defined for the class
>   'RouteSettings'**.
> - **'RouteSettings' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart'**
>   ('/D:/FlutterSDK/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
>   a method named 'copyWith'.
>   settings = settings.copyWith(name: absolutePath);
>   ^^^^^^^^ /C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/states_rebuilder-4.4.0/lib/src/navigate/rm_navigator.dart:613:29:
>   Error: **The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter
>   type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.**
>   semanticsDismissible: semanticsDismissible,
>   ^ Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'D:\FlutterSDK\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line:
>   1201
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
> > Process 'command 'D:\FlutterSDK\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 22s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> 83.8s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I am using Editor: VS Code

Below is the output from *flutter doctor -v*

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.22621.1992], locale en-GB)
> • Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable at d:\FlutterSDK
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision f468f3366c (3 weeks ago), 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
> • Engine revision cdbeda788a
> • Dart version 3.0.6
> • DevTools version 2.23.1
>
> [√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or
> higher)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 31.0.0)
> • Android SDK at C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
> • Platform android-33, build-tools 31.0.0
> • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>
> [!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022
> 17.4.1)
> • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
> • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.4.33110.190
> X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop
> development with C++" workload, and include these components:
> MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
> - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
> C++ CMake tools for Windows
> Windows 10 SDK
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.80.2)
> • VS Code at C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
> • Flutter extension version 3.68.0
>
> [√] Connected device (4 available)
> • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
> • Windows (desktop)                  • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.22621.1992]
> • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.248
> • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 115.0.1901.188
>
> [√] Network resources
> • All expected network resources are available.
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

I've done flutter pub upgrade, but still the error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue - ran `flutter pub deps` to get a tree view of all the dependencies, to see which one was using the offending package.

```
├── animator 3.1.0
│   ├── flutter...
│   └── states_rebuilder4.4.0
│       ├── collection... 
│       └── flutter... 
├── cached_network_image 3.2.3
```

So, it was *animator* package, using *states_rebuilder*, which had the offending code. Removed the package altogether and it now builds just fine